# PHP Require content rather than file?

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

This is quite a weird question, but I thought it was an interesting one anyway.

I'm working on a module similar to **Laravel's Blade Templating Engine**, which can take a page and parse it using PHP, though I testing my engine and I used this page:

```
<form method="post">
  {{ csrf_make() }}

  <?php $form('formId')->row()->half()->text('Username')->endhalf()endrow(); ?>
</form>
```

(*No need to worry what the actual PHP does, just the line itself*)

Now, my engine will pull the data from the page using `file_get_contents( $path_to_file )`, then parse the content then output it to the `View/Entry` of the webpage.

I expected `file_get_contents` to parse the PHP, then return the data, but instead the output for the **WEBPAGE** was:

```
$form('formId')->row()->half()->text('Username')->endhalf()endrow(); ?>
```

Meaning the page wasn't ran through the PHP interpreter/compiler; and just pulling the actual raw data from the file itself.

I was thinking of some alternatives to this, and I was going towards a `cURL` url pull of the file itself, or being able to some-what `require` in the page without specifying the directory, and specifying the data, like:

```
require_data( "<form> <?php echo 'some php'; ?> </form>" );
```

If that makes sense.

Comment: If you are using a path when you tried with `file_get_contents($path_to_file);`, then why not use `include($path_to_file);` or the like? What is the issue you are having that is the main problem doing it this way?

Comment: Since `include` will include the file which is correct, but then after parsing the PHP file it outputs the file, I need a middle bit for after including the file so I can parse it again using my engine. @Rasclatt

Comment: If you run it through a function that captures the include between an output buffer, you can take that buffer and parse that through your engine. That way it runs the PHP as well.

Comment: Would that be similar to an `ob_start()` / `ob_get_clean` then including the data? Cause I just thought that would work.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am referring to. `ob_start(); include($path); $data = ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean();` Then run the `$data` through your parser

Comment: Thanks so much! :') Will add this to my codebase now. @Rasclatt

Comment: @Rasclatt `ob_start();include($path);$str=ob_get_clean();` , ob_get_clean does the job of both ob_get_contents and ob_end_clean in a single call